# How to use PrimeNg Toast correctly in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

It is working, but not as It should. Instead of a proper `toast` component, message is simply displayed as a normal text after i press submit button.
[image]

I followed everything written ni the Documentation. Here are my files.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.3",
    ...
  },
```

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.css",
   "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
   "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
   "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
],
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...        
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
    ToastModule
  ],
  providers: [MessageService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**contribute.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/components/common/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contribute',
  templateUrl: './contribute.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contribute.component.css']
})
export class ContributeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService, ...) { }

  addSingle() {
    this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Service Message', detail:'Via MessageService'});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
  }

  onSubmit() {
    ...
    this.addSingle();
  }
}
```

**contribute.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 bg-light">
      <form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          ...SOME INPUT FIELDS
        </div>
        <p-toast position="top-left"></p-toast>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-3">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I mean, Its working. But not like a good `toast` component. Please correct me.

Comment: can you try by moving the <p-toast> out of your form?

Comment: Tried. But No Sir. Not working. The text is now displayed below the button. Still not getting proper `toast` component.

Comment: Are you sure, that the contribute component is under the app module and not in any other module?

Comment: Yes. It is there in the `declarations` array. It is there. Yes I am sure.

Comment: @Tanzeel check this it is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewtxe4

Comment: Ok. I'll create a fresh project and test this again. No other choice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Angular 8: Try the following method

**Pre Steps:**

In app.module.ts:

```
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/messages';
import { MessageModule } from 'primeng/message';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
```

and under the imports

```
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MessagesModule,
        MessageModule,
        ToastModule,
],
```

Step 1: Inject the message service in component for your choice like below

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
```

Step 2: On the same component, you need to add providers like below

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-import-project',
    templateUrl: './import-project.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./import-project.component.css'],
    providers: [MessageService],
})
```

Step 3: Declare the message service in constructor

```
  constructor(
        private messageService: MessageService,
        private router: Router,
        private progress: NgProgress
    ) {}
```

Step 4: On the same `component.ts file:` Assuming you want to throw error message

```
   showError() {
    console.log('Authentication Failed');
    this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'error',
        summary: 'Authentication Failed',
        detail: 'API Key or URL is invalid.',
    });
}
```

Step 5: In the relevant.html file. Add the HTML tag like below

```
<p-toast position="bottom-center"></p-toast>
```

Output: This should definitely throw the proper toast like below

Hope this will solve your problem instead of creating new project every time. Please give a try.

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation, but can you help with following scenario, I put p-toast in shared component, but it is not working on first click,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709915/not-getting-opened-on-first-click-when-putting-primeng-toast-on-shared-component

Comment: Excellent walkthrough (and clearer than primeNg's own brief explanation).

Comment: @MikeGledhill Glad it helped you :)

Comment: Can we make the toast messages as a common? Like only one service as central and only one toast message tag?

Comment: @kushalBaldev, yes you can make a shared module and make this service as common

Comment: I am little bit confused how to make it common i know that we require toast module that I already imported in shared module secondly we would require MessageService in providers but how can I add the providers in service and thirdly we need to add the p toast message tag on each component we want so can you give me little of a hint what I need to do or can add sample code It would be great help to me thanks....!!!